# why wont my player move in python

Tags: python, pygame

My player won't move and I don't understand why. I followed a tutorial on how to make it move. I did what the person did but it doesn't move for me.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("use arows")





class player:

    def __init__(self ,x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32
        self.velocity = 0
        self.falling = False
        self.onGround = False

    def detectCollisions(self,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):

        if (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

            return True

        elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

            return True

        elif (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

            return True

        elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

            return True

        else:

            return False

    def update(self, gravity, blockList):
        if (self.velocity < 0):
            self.falling = True

        collision = False
        blockX,blockY =  0,0
        for block in blockList:

            collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height )
            if collision == True:
                blockx = block.x
                blocky = block.y
                break


        if(collision == True):
            if (self.falling == True):
                self.falling == False
                self.onGround== True
                self.velocity = 0
                self.y = blocky - self.height

        if (self.onGround == False):
            self.velocity += gravity
        self.y -= self.velocity

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


class Block:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.width = 32
       self.height = 32

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))



gravity = -0.5

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (50,60,200)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player(0,0)

# 25 colums and 19 rows
level1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

blockList = []

for y in range (0,len(level1)):
    for x in range (0,len(level1[y])):
        if (level1[y][x] == 1):
            blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))

movex,movey=0,0

gameloop = True
while gameloop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameloop = False

    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
            movex = 5

        elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
            movex = -5


    if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
            movex = 0

        elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
           movex = 0

    screen.fill(blue)

    for block in blockList:
        block.render(screen)

    player.update(gravity, blockList)
    player.render(screen)
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nesting issue in your gameloop. The checks for the event actions need to be inside the for loop, so it checks each event during the frame. It is only checking the last event as it currently is coded.

Indent your event checks like so:

```
gameloop = True
while gameloop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameloop = False

        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                movex = 5

            elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                movex = -5


        if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                movex = 0

            elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                movex = 0
```

**Edit:**

In addition to the above, the `movex` variable is not being used, and, indeed, your player update function has no means of horizontal movement in it.

You'll need to make a few update to your Player class:

```
def __init__(self ,x, y):

    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 32
    self.height = 32
    self.yVelocity = 0
    self.xVelocity = 0 #Add xVelocity variable to track horizontal speed.
    self.falling = False
    self.onGround = False


def update(self, gravity, blockList):
    if (self.yVelocity < 0):
        self.falling = True

    collision = False
    blockX,blockY =  0,0
    for block in blockList:

        collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height )
        if collision == True:
            blockx = block.x
            blocky = block.y
            break


    if(collision == True):
        if (self.falling == True):
            self.falling == False
            self.onGround== True
            self.yVelocity = 0
            self.xVelocity = 0 #On a collision, stop all movement.
            self.y = blocky - self.height

    if (self.onGround == False):
        self.yVelocity += gravity
    self.y -= self.yVelocity
    self.x -= self.xVelocity #Modify position according to velocity.
```

Then, in your game loop, update the player's xVelocity according to the input:

```
player.xVelocity = movex #Update horizontal velocity.
player.update(gravity, blockList)
player.render(screen)
clock.tick(60)
```

That should help.

Comment: that didn't seem to fix it. just showing you i did it / see if i did it right http://prntscr.com/8o71ub

Comment: If that didn't work, there must be another issue as well. Give me a second to look over the code again.

Comment: `movex` isn't actually being used for anything, so modifying it won't cause any action. You'll need to set the horizontal speed of the player to `movex`, but the update function only uses `velocity`, which is for vertical motion. You'll need to add horizontal movement to the update function.

Comment: okay so i added player.x = move x and have move x = 0  but now when i move as it only moves like 1 or so pixels and then it stops and when i let go of my key ( the right key) it goes back to where it started, so i changed the starting point of the player to 400,0 and it still started at 0,0 and fell to the bottom and did that same thing

Comment: on the tutorial he didn't do any of that he just added player.x = move.x

Comment: i just copied all the code you said into my thing and indented it right and now it doesn't move at all

Comment: "on the tutorial he didn't do any of that he just added player.x = move.x" Are you sure that wasn't `player.x += movex` ?

Comment: "i just copied all the code you said into my thing and indented it right and now it doesn't move at all" - That's likely an issue with your collision detection. You should probably remove the `self.xVelocity = 0` line under `if(collision==True):` until you can update the collision detection to be less sensitive, and differentiate x and y collisions.

Comment: it worked but now its backwards xD left moves it right and visa versa i can just change the key pressed so backwards to fix it probably